# how to redirect to aspx page in a controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is it possible to redirect to an aspx page in an (asp.net-mvc3 )controller action?
 What should be  the return type of the action (ActionResult?) and which redirect method should be called (RedirectToAction?).

BR,

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can redirect to anywhere from MVC action and you have to use `RedirectResult` for that. `RedirectResult` is a type of `ActionResult`.

For ex.

```
public RedirectResult RedirectToAspx()
{
  return Redirect("/pages/index.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just like razor.

View:

```
test.aspx
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult test()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "test。";

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: okay, what about query string params? I need to call XxReport.aspx?requestID=some-guid-id, when I do this, it says it cannot find it.

Comment: it does not work. by the way, aspx page is a web-form page, not an MVC-aspx page.

Comment: Oh, I thought was MVC-aspx. I'm so sorry.