# MVC, how to post data to controller and redirect to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC view where user can set a flag and post data to controller (post because I want to hidden query string)

After the controller have done his job I want to redirect to website home page that is an aspx page (my site is mixed aspx and MVC)

Is there a way to do that?

This is my view

```
@model MessaggiVM
<form role="form" class="form-inline" method="post" action="Messaggi/VaiAllaHome">
    <button id="btnHome">Vai alla pagina iniziale</button>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nascondi">hiding</label>
        <input id="nascondi" type="checkbox" name="nascondi" value="true" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="elencoPost" value="@Model.Posts" />
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Messaggi", "VaiAllaHome", new { posts = Model.Posts} )*@
</form>
```

And this the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectResult VaiAllaHome(bool? nascondi = false, IEnumerable<Messaggio> elencoPost = null)
{
    // do something

    return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
}
```

When I run this code controller action is executed without error but redirect is not done and browser remain on the view

Other problem is that elencoPost parameter is empty in the action but I'm investigating it

EDIT

Honestly I'm thinking to post data on input change and switch button for a simply link

EDIT 2:

found the reason: in default.aspx i have a auto-redirect to Message page :(

Comment: these links should help you: For Post: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639709/Getting-Data-From-View-to-Controller-in-MVC and for redirect to aspx: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12977284/3365113

Comment: Try `return Redirect("/SomePage");`

Comment: i have to use "~/" for the root of website, iam under reverse proxy and relative link cant work

Comment: What happens if you try `return Redirect("~/")`?

Comment: same thing, view is simply refreshed

Comment: do you have a try catch statement inside your action with a `"return View();"` in your catch segment?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in order to send a Enumerable or List to your controller you need to actually enumerate them in your view first and later declare them in your action parameters. A `foreach` would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
return Redirect("~/home.aspx");
```

or

```
return Redirect(Url.Content("~/home.aspx")
```

Comment: found the reason: in default.aspx i have a auto-redirect to Message page :(. mark this as accepted since is the more relevant

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `Redirect` with a relative url:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public RedirectResult VaiAllaHome(bool? nascondi = false, IEnumerable<Messaggio> elencoPost = null)
    {
        // do something

        return Redirect("/home.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using a @Url.Content on your form tag

```
<form action="@Url.Content("~/Messaggi/VaiAllaHome/")">
```

Then in your Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectResult VaiAllaHome(bool? nascondi = false, IEnumerable<Messaggio> elencoPost = null)
{
    // do something

    return View(Url.Content("~/"));
    //return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { routeParameter = value } /*e.g. "id = 1"*/);
}
```

Comment: OP says he is trying to redirect to an ASP.NET Web Forms .aspx page